# Как подключить OpenCV к проекту Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

Подключил библиотеку opencv через vcpkg, запустил программу по выводу точек и в принципе все получилось, однако сам код помечается большим количеством ошибок

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "apple_carving.hpp"
int main() {
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 1000, CV_8UC3);
std::vector<cv::Point> points = {
    cv::Point(100, 100),
    cv::Point(200, 200),
    cv::Point(300, 300),
    cv::Point(400, 400),
    cv::Point(430, 100),
    cv::Point(100, 430)
};
for (const auto& point : points) {
    cv::circle(img, point, 5, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 255), -1);
}
cv::imshow("Test_image", img);
cv::waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

[image: вот как выглядит код в самом компиляторе...]

```
project ("apple_carving")

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY PREDEFINED_TARGETS_FOLDER "cmake")

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True) 


set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin.dbg)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin.rel)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin.relwithdbg)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_subdirectory ("apple_carving")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не найден `include` каталог. Где то в кишках Visual Studio есть настройки проекта (не подскажу, 100 лет не пользовался и не хочу). Если используется CMake, - добавьте через него.

Comment: А почему сам код тогда работает? Картинка с точками выводится, понять не могу...

Comment: Значит это баг. Не секрет, что Visual Studio забагован =)

Comment: Почистите кэш, удалите каталог билда

Comment: То есть удалить папку build и запустить заново? Простите за глупые вопросы, просто мало опыта в программировании(

Comment: через CMake добавил каталог, но все равно что-то не так...

Comment: Код CMake'а в студию

Comment: Добавил в описание вопроса

Comment: Вы не добавили в `find_package` необходимые модули

Comment: Например: `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS opencv_core opencv_videoio)`

Comment: А как понять что именно добавить?

Comment: Документацию читайте

Comment: Кажется у OpenCV был билд с одим модулем, объединящем все.

Comment: На самом деле, самый простой способ выяснить, какие модули есть, можно просто в кишках билда либы покопаться (`CMakeLists.txt`,`*.cmake`)

Comment: Такое ощущение, что проблема не в модулях, так как, как вы и сказали, они все включены. Проблема в том, что ошибкой помечается сам include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>, что совсем странно, потому что по факту opencv работает.

Comment: Может быть ошибка в этом моменте? Хотя я вроде бы указал правильный путь, до opencv.hpp(фото снова прикрепил к описанию "добавление в путь включаемых файлов")

Comment: выйдите из VS и удалите .vs, IntelliSense кэш постоянно сбоит

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не поменялось(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для линковки сторонних библиотек нужно сделать следующие действия:

1. Нажать на проект ПКМ и выбрать пункт `"Свойства"`
2. Перейти в пункт `С/C++` -> `Общие` и найти пункт `"Дополнительные каталоги включают"` и вставить полный путь к библиотеке, в таком формате `C:\Users\user\Desktop\cryptopp` (`cryptopp` взял для примера)
3. Зайти в пункт `Компоновщик` -> `Ввод` -> `"Дополнительные зависимости"` и добавить зависимость для библиотеки `OpenCV` с расширением `.lib`

Более конкретно все показано на [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XE4zEN-WKg), где линкуют библиотеку `cryptopp`, но вместо этой библиотеки вам нужно будет подключить именно `OpenCV`.
Надеюсь, это вам поможет.

Изменено: забыл уточнить, в видео еще показывают как сбилдить (собрать) библиотеку, чтобы появилась зависимость с расширением `.lib`, это на случай если у вас нет зависимости с таким расширением для `OpenCV`, правда там скорее всего другие методы для того, чтобы собрать библиотеку так, как вам надо.